# React - display answer as a list

Tags: reactjs, mapping

I am creating a react quiz app but I'm trying to figure out how to get my answer array to show as a list. This is my code so far

Load data succesfully loads the data from an api, when i do a console log on my answers variable I can see an array for each question with four answers which is correct.

```
const loadData = async () => {
  let response = await fetch(
    "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=22&difficulty=medium&type=multiple"
  );
  const data = await response?.json();
  console.log(data);

  const getQuestions = data.results.map((item) => {
    const question = item.question;

     const answers = [...item.incorrect_answers, item.correct_answer];
   
//console.log(answers) shows this as an example 
 ["Quebec", "Ontario", "Nova Scotia", "Alberta"]

    return {
      question: question,
      answers: answers,
    };
  });
  return getQuestions;
};



function App() {
//create useState hook to pass data into
const [showData, setData] = useState([]);

//pass the data into a useeffect hook and setData to the loadData method from above
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const getData = await loadData();
      setData(getData);
      
    })();
  }, []);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {showData.map((data) => (
        <>
          <div>
            <h1>{data.question}</h1>
          
          <ul>{data.answers}</ul>
         </div>
        </>
      ))}
 
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

The return function outputs the question but if i try to display the answers as a list so I can get each one seperately, it just puts them on the same line.

e.g:
Which city is the capital of Switzerland?
Zürich,Frankfurt,Wien,Bern

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate the answers array instead of rendering them directly.
Also ul  is the parent tag for unordered list, you should use li for listing the children.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showData, setData] = useState([]);
  const loadData = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=22&difficulty=medium&type=multiple"
    );
    const data = await response?.json();
    console.log(data);

    const getQuestions = data.results.map((item) => {
      const question = item.question;
      const answers = [...item.incorrect_answers, item.correct_answer];
      return {
        question: question,
        answers: answers
      };
    });
    return getQuestions;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const getData = await loadData();
      setData(getData);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {showData.map((data,i) => (
        <>
          <div key={i}>
            <h4>{data.question}</h4>
            // map the answers separately
            {data.answers.map((item,j)=><li key={j}>{item}</li>)}
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Check code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-leftpad-zcwew?file=/src/App.js:0-1063

Comment: Thankyou, this worked! The issue must be because my load data function was outside of the app. The data.answers.map only worked once I bought all the code inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate though your `answers` array with another `map`:

```
<ul>
  {
    data.answers.map((answer) =>
       // It's a good practice to apply a unique identifier as key to your list
       // Not the index, however, as it may change 
       <li key={someValue}>answer</li> 
    ) 
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thankyou! the load data function was outside of the app and it wouldn't recognise the data.answers.map until I put all the code inside the app function

Comment: No problem, glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out ‍♂️**

```js
function App() {
  //create useState hook to pass data into
  const [showData, setData] = useState([]);

  //pass the data into a useeffect hook and setData to the loadData method from above
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const getData = await loadData();
      setData(getData);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {showData.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <div>
              <h1>{data.question}</h1>
              <ul>
              {data.answers.map((answer, index) => {
                return (
                  <li key={index}>{answer}</li>
                )
              })}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here:

1. `<ul>{data.answers}</ul>` won't work because `data.answers` is an array. You'll need to map the elements of this array into `<li>` elements just as you did in the parent.
2. Whenever you use `map` to create a list, you must add a unique key on each element, typically an id. I assume questions and answers are unique, so you can use the data itself as the key.
3. Your code doesn't check `response.ok` before accessing `response.json()`. Yes, you do use a question mark operator here so that specific operation is safe, but then the `undefined.results` on the next line crashes, so it just pushes the buck and obfuscates the `fetch` error further.
4. Remove the superfluous fragment `<>`.
5. In es6, `{questions: questions}` can just be `{questions}`.
6. Don't forget to shuffle your answers when you continue working on the app.

```html
<script type="text/babel" defer>
const {Fragment, useEffect, useState} = React;

const loadData = async (
  url="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=22&difficulty=medium&type=multiple"
) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.status);
  }

  return (await response.json()).results.map(
    ({question, incorrect_answers, correct_answer}) => ({
      question,
      answers: [...incorrect_answers, correct_answer]
    })
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData()
      .then(setData)
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
    ;
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {data.map(({question, answers}) => (
        <div key={question}>
          <h3>{question}</h3>
          <ul>
            {answers.map(a => <li key={a}>{a}</li>)}
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. The 3rd point is particularly helpful and I think that's why the data.answers.map did not work while loadData was outside of the app function. Thanks for the tips :)